# Ruby Bracket Method with Block

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I would like to define the `[]` method on a class of my own creation to take a block. I have done so as follows.

```
class A
  def self.[](*args, &block)
    puts "I am calling #{block} on #{args}."
    block.(*args)
  end
end
```

I can invoke this as follows.

```
# Explicit method invocation
A.[](1) { |x| puts x }
# With a procedure argument
arg = proc { |x| puts x }
A[2, &arg]
```

However, what I would like to be able to do is this.

```
A[3] { |x| puts x }
```

Which unfortunately seems to produce a syntax error. Is there a block syntax for the bracket method, or am I stuck with the first two ways of invoking it? In fact, more generally, which Ruby method names will allow blocks in their invocation, as it seems that there might be a limitation on when this is allowed?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. `A.send('[]', 3) { |x| puts x }` is an alternative, but not so fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do against a syntax error, so you'll have to change the syntax.

If you accept :

- to define (i.e. pollute) an uppercase method inside `Kernel` (similar to [`Kernel#Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array))
- to use parens instead of brackets

You could write :

```
class A
  def self.call_block_with_args(*args, &block)
    puts "I am calling #{block} on #{args}."
    block.call(*args)
  end
end

module Kernel
  def A(*args, &block)
    A.call_block_with_args(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

It works this way :

```
A(3) { |x| puts x }
#=>
# I am calling #<Proc:0x000000012b9c50@block_brackets.rb:14> on [3].
# 3
```

It's not clean, but it's probably the closest you can be to `A[3] { |x| puts x }`.

Comment: I liked the solution, didn't know about kernel module +1

Answer (score 2):

Blocks work with normal method calls only.

Ruby has plenty of operators, listing all of them here would be exhaustive, there are more than two dozens. Even `` `a` `` and  `!a` and `-a` are method calls in Ruby. And obviously there are limitations to all these operators, eg `+` must take one parameter but not more, et cetera.

Fun fact, `loop` is a method call too.